# Different structs in the same node Linked Lists C

Tags: c, struct, adt

I am having a bit of difficulty with my assignment and was wondering if someone can point me in the right path.

I wish to create a linked list which supports the use of different nodes, as I need different data sets to be used.

At the moment I am using three structs:

```
struct equipment_data {
    char EquipID[4+1]; /* 4 Max */
    char EquipName[31+1]; /* 31 Max */
    unsigned TotalNumber;
};

struct member_data {
    unsigned MemberID;
    char LastName[31+1]; /* 31 Max */
    char FirstName[31+1]; /* 31 Max */
};

struct loan_data {
    unsigned MemberID;
    char EquipID[4+1]; /* 4 Max */
    unsigned Number;
};
```

I need to somehow use this within the same node.

```
struct ets {
    struct node *equipment_data;
    struct node *member_data;
    struct node *loan_data;
    unsigned equip_count;
    unsigned member_count;
    unsigned loan_count;
};

struct node {
    void *data;
    struct node *next;
};
```

Looks like I need to create an ADT Linked List. Could you please help? Thanks!

Comment: You need that you have to access the all structure using the single variable?

Comment: Here is a site where you can experiment: http://www.learn-c.org/en/Linked_lists

Comment: The most common way is not to have generic lists, but make each of the separate structures nodes in their own list. If you want to make a generic list, then you already have it with the `node` structure, just make `data` point to the correct structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would make structures for the types that you need to support, and then a union with a type indicator in the linked list node:

```
typedef struct { int a, b, c;    } Type1;
typedef struct { char buf[80];   } Type2;
typedef struct { int a; float b; } Type3;

typedef union {
    Type1 t1,
    Type2 t2,
    Type3 t3;
} Anytype;

typedef struct node {
    int thistype;   // 1 for type1, 2 for type2 etc.
    Anytype data;
    struct node *next;
} Listnode;
```

Just make sure that you set the `thistype` right in each `Listnode`.

```
Listnode *node = malloc(sizeof(Listnode));
node->thistype = 1;  // example: Type1, the 3 ints
node->t1.a = 1;
node->t1.b = 2;
node->t1.c = 3;
node->next = someothernode;
```

The you can use a `switch` to access the data:

```
Listnode *node;
switch (node->thistype) {
    case 1: 
        // do stuff with node->t1.a, node->t1.b, node->t1.c
        break
    case 2:
        // do stuff with node->t2.buf
        break;
    case 3:
        // do stuff with node->t3.a, node.t3.b
        break
}
```

Comment: If the next pointer is moved so that it is the first member of the node structures, then a common set of list functions (append, insert, delete), can be used with any of the nodes, using a "base" node structure that only contains a next pointer (and optionally a type for the second member, perhaps define the "base" node structure as type0 ) . This would be similar to inherited classes in C++. C / C++ guarantees that the address of the first member of a structure is the same as the address of the structure, which is why this would work.

Answer (score 2):

Enumerate the datatypes you want to store

```
typedef enum type{ equipment, member,loan,ets} type;    
typedef struct lnk_lst
{
  type data_type;
  void* data;
  struct lnk_lst* next;
} lnk_lst ;
```

Initilization will be like

```
equipment_data e1;
lnk_lst* node=(lnk_lst*)malloc(sizeof(lnk_lst));
node->data_type=equipment;

//if created dynamically
   node->data=malloc(sizeof(equipment_data));
//just to point existing equipment_data
   node->data=(void*)(&e1);

node->next=NULL;
```

Assessing the list will be like

```
switch(node->data_type)
{
 case equipment:
   printf("%d",((equipment_data*)(node->data))->TotalNumber);
   puts( ((equipment_data*)(node->data))->EquipID );
   puts( ((equipment_data*)(node->data))->EquipName );
 case member:
   //code to read member_data
 case loan:
   //code to read loan_data
 case ets:
   //code to read ets
 }
```

Comment: I don't recommend using union because loan_data has size of 13 bytes considering int as 4 byte whereas member_data has size 68 byte. If you use union you will be using 68 byte to store loan_data also. Which  is big waste of memory.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably create a node that has points to the various structs.

```
struct node {
struct equipment_data *eq_data; // This pointers to equipment struct
struct member_data * me_data; // ......
struct load_data * lo_data; // .....
unsigned equip_count;
unsigned member_count;
unsigned loan_count;
struct node* next_node; // this points to the next node in the 

};
```

Answer (score 1):

you can place the variable for the structure ets in the struct node.

```
struct node {
void *data;
struct ets *var;
struct node *next;
};
```

Now you can access the all structures.